# MySQL: Get product with most recent price for each store

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the two tables below, there can be many price entries against one product,I'm looking to output the product name with the most recent product information for each store. I'm using the below but not getting the expected result, there can be hundreds products with hundreds of price records each with hundreds of stores I've only two here as an example.

**product**

```
product_id | name      | cat_id
---------------------------------
1          | product 1 | 124567
2          | product 2 | 834392
3          | product 3 | 234723
```

**price**

```
product_id  | price | store | added
--------------------------------------------------
1           | 1.00  | 1     | 2016-01-01 00:00:00
1           | 1.50  | 2     | 2016-01-01 00:00:00
2           | 3.75  | 1     | 2016-01-01 00:00:00
2           | 4.00  | 2     | 2016-01-01 00:10:00
2           | 3.99  | 2     | 2016-01-01 00:00:00
3           | 34.56 | 1     | 2016-01-01 00:00:00
```

**Expected Output**

```
name        | price | store | added
--------------------------------------------------
product 1   | 1.00  | 1     | 2016-01-01 00:00:00
product 1   | 1.50  | 2     | 2016-01-01 00:00:00
product 2   | 3.75  | 1     | 2016-01-01 00:00:00
product 2   | 4.00  | 2     | 2016-01-01 00:10:00
proudct 3   | 34.56 | 1     | 2016-01-01 00:00:00
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT `prod`.`name`
, `prc`.`price`
, `prc`.`store`
, `prc`.`added`
FROM `product` `prod`
LEFT JOIN `price` `prc` ON `prod`.`product_id` = `prc`.`product_id`
ORDER BY `prod`.`cat_id` DESC
, `prc`.`added` DESC
, `prc`.`price` DESC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to eliminate price rows where *there exists a newer price for the same store/product*;

```
SELECT name, price, store, added
FROM product
JOIN price 
  ON product.product_id = price.product_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM price p 
  WHERE price.product_id = p.product_id
    AND price.store = p.store
    AND price.added < p.added
);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5e84/1).

Answer (score 0):

your query should updated to be:

```
SELECT `prod`.`name`
, max(`prc`.`price`)
, `prc`.`store`
, `prc`.`added`
FROM `product` `prod`
LEFT JOIN `price` `prc` ON `prod`.`product_id` = `prc`.`product_id`
group by `prod`.`name`, `prc`.`store`
ORDER BY `prod`.`cat_id` DESC
, `prc`.`added` DESC
, `prc`.`price` DESC;
```